# What is the precedence of Lombok annotations?

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I know that `@EqualsAndHashCode` have a precedence over `@Data`, but what about other annotations? Is there any simple rule that can be used to determine it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know just one rule: A more specific annotation takes precedence. As `@Data` doesn't allow to configure anything about the `@EqualsAndHashCode` computation details, the latter is clearly more specific. Similarly for `@Data` vs. `@Getter` and others.

Another case is class-level vs. field-level annotation, where the former can be overridden by the latter.

Note that doing it the other way round would make no sense at all.

There are some border cases like `@Builder` vs. `@Data`, where it's unclear what constructor should be generated (IIRC they require `AllArgsConstructor` and `NoArgsContructor`, respectively). Specifying the constructors explicitly helps.